# Uber REST API calls have high response time. Is there a was to improve them?

Tags: performance, uber-api

we develop an intermodal travel app which integrates Uber with the Uber REST API. I made some calls using curl to the following API services:

- api.uber.com/v1.2/products
- api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/time
- api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price

All calls have response times between 1 and 1.5 seconds. I find these response times quite high. Is there a way to improve the response times of the API?
Thanx & kind regards
Jean-Marc

Comment: Hello, thanks for the report. That is a higher latency than what we are seeing at those endpoints, but latency and response times can be impacted by a large number of factors (geo, connection speed, etc). So no specific recommendations, but the Uber API team is always working to ensure the platform is as scalable and fast as we can.

Comment: Ok, I was making the call from our corporate network through our web proxy. I now tested this call with curl over my home WLAN and internet provider and get with curl response time around 800 to 900 ms. Much better.
Then I tried to call the service using postman and there I get
 - about 250 ms for /products
 - about 250 ms for /estimates/time
 - about 400 ms for /estimates/price

These are the response times I was expected. So it seems that curl have a big overhead and cannot be used for time measurement of APIs. 
And our Web Proxy have a big overhead as well.

Comment: @Jean-MarcTerrettaz Could you please explain what how you used Postman. Did you use it with python?

Comment: No I used the Postman app on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High response times were caused by

- corporate reverse proxy
- overhead using curl